# Android GridView Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Como colocar linhas entre as células em uma gridview. Para que não pareça que os itens estejam flutuando. Exemplo como colunas e linhas de um excel e se é possível alterar a cor de alguma célula de forma especifica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma como eu faço isso é muito simples, preencho o fundo da GridView com uma cor, os itens com outra cor e adiciono o espaçamento entre itens, e ai tens uma grelha com limites, tipo tabela. Podes depois conjugar essas opções para criar efeitos bonitos.

Exemplo de código [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311057/1817673):

```
GridView gv = findViewById(R.id.my_grid_view);
gv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
gv.setVerticalSpacing(1);
gv.setHorizontalSpacing(1);
```

Comment: Bem criativa esta solução, estava pesquisando e a única forma que achei era colocar bordas no itens do `GridView`. Achei bem legal. +1